# When Operation Bloodhound ends will I stop getting weekly bloodhound drops?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Bloodhound is going to end tomorrow and I want to know if bloodhound drops will stop. That's really my only reason to play without my friends and I want to know because if not I'm going to try and cram in a last drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>While we don't know when exactly Valve will end Operation Bloodhound, as they typically do extend the duration of the operation like they did for Breakout, Vanguard, etc, once an operation ends all of the associated operation drops typically disappear along with it.</strike>

But remember, this is the first time we've had a system where guaranteed Operation drops for Operation owners every week were set in place.   In previous Operations once they were removed, access to the Missions then were removed as well.   Since Operation drops are no longer received from missions, I would say that once Bloodhound leaves, so will the drops.

As Operation Bloodhound has already ended, so have the weekly drop system using the newest weapon collections. Instead, players can still receive a guranteed weekly drop that will pull from the current weapon drop collection (Italy, Train, etc.).

Comment: Thanks!!! I'm hoping they'll extend it but too bad because those drops gave me hope I would get a cool skin

Comment: I think you can get at most blue skins via _normal drops_ after a match. For better ones you have to open cases actively.

Comment: Untrue. Some collections have purple rarity items as well